# Virtualenv not detecting pip3

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I'm having problems running pip3 from virtualenv. If I run 'pip3 install django' in my active virtualenv, it will try to install it in my virtualenv, but fail because need privileges. The problem is, that when I use 'sudo pip3 install django', installs django globally. How can I avoid that?

Comment: Inside your virtualenv, you should only need to use `pip`. Virtualenv will reference the correct `pip` for the `python` installed in your virtualenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I solved it reinstalling virtualenv. 
Thanks to Klaus D.

**ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION**

If everything else fail, you can still use pip explicitly:

```
myvirtualenv/bin/pip3 install django==1.7.1
```

and when you create your virtualenv do it without sudo, like:

```
virtualenv myvirtualenv --no-site-packages
```

Thanks to cesarkawakami from #python freenode irc.

Comment: I guess you forgot to enter the virtual environment with `workon` before installing?

Comment: I'm using virtualenv, not virtualenvwrapper.

Comment: OK, in the virtualenv wording then: Did you `activate` the environment?

Comment: Yes, and pip failed when i just run 'pip3 install' instead of 'myvirtualenv/bin/pip3 install'

Comment: In this case you should check if the PATH and the other VARIABLES in the environment have been set properly. You did not write anything on your OS, so I can't give further details.

Comment: I reinstalled virtualenv, and now i can use pip from my virtualenv, thanks for your help, updating solution.

Comment: Careful of directory names with spaces. I realized I was in one when I got the pip3 not found error. After I re-created working directory without spaces - it worked. Go figure.